# PHP display assigned users for each task

Tags: php, mysql

I created a tasks app and they asked me to allow a user to assign a task to multiple users. So I created a pivot table (tasks_users) with 3 columns, "id, task_id, user_id"

The question is: What is the optimum way to display the users for each task? Cause the way I did it seems dumb, even though it works. Here is the code.

```
<?php foreach ($tasks as $task): ?>

   <div class="todo-tasklist-item todo-tasklist-item-border-<?php echo $task->status ?> testclass" id="task_click" data-tstatus="<?php echo $task->status ?>" data-tname="<?php echo $task->task_name?>" data-projectid="<?php echo $task->project_id?>" data-taskid="<?php echo $task->task_id?>">

      <?php foreach ($assigned_users as $user): ?>

         <?php if($task->task_id == $user->task_id): ?>                                                                                          

            <img class="todo-userpic pull-left" src="http://localhost/metro/assets/pages/media/users/<?php echo $user->avatar ?>" width="27px" height="27px">

         <?php endif; ?>

      <?php endforeach; ?>

   </div>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is just a piece of the code. It works well, but I'm not sure if it's a good way to do it as eventually I'll have thousands and thousands of records in my tasks_users table and I believe that I'm looping through the whole table for each task I display.

Comment: if that block works okay then just leave it. just add a pagination, you wouldn't want to fetch the whole table row when the data grows big

Comment: @Ghost read my mind. If you have thousands of records, why would you want a page that shows all the tasks? It will be very user-unfriendly (long load times, laggy browser...)

Comment: I didn't mean thousands of tasks, I meant thousands of records in the pivot table. Even if I'm displaying only 10 tasks per page, what happens when I loop through the pivot table looking for the 'user_id's that match the task displayed? Won't it loop through the whole pivot table (this one with thousand and thousand of records) anyway?

Comment: Like ghost said you should use a pageinator . Then its importent that you do a limied query to fetsch the data from the database. The code is not bad ... But for a scalable application i would prefere a template engine like twig. But the importent part is, your $tasks array should never be too big .